# Spring not initializing session bean with requestcontextlistener

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I am trying to decouple my webapp from enunciate and I have a web.xml as follows but when Spring 3 bootstraps I get:

> Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method:.... Scope 'session' is not active for the current
>   thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend
>   to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

The thing is I have a request context listener:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.mypackage.web</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.providers</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.mypackage.web.rest.SerializableProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/myurl/session</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So why does Spring not boot properly? Could it be because its thread related and sessionbean to sessionbean?

Answer (score 0):

According to error you can not autowire session scope class because your singleton classes loaded when application starts. In the beginning session does not exist.

You need to create proxy interface

ex : @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)